# Will my missed prayers be counted as negligence if I leave them due to lapse of time?

Tags: prayer-timings, fajr

I was 7 minutes away from sunrise when I woke up for fajr. I didn't pray due to the reason I mentioned. Also I wasn't sure about exact time of sunrise. So I finally let it go. I have set daily alarm but I don't remember if I woke up on it or due to dominant sleep I just turned it off while it was ringing. Will this be counted in my negligence?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wake up for fajr, even if it is late you can pray as soon as possible.

> 'The Prophet was asked about a man who forgets prayer or sleeps and
> misses it. He said: 'he performs it when he remembers it.'"
> https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:695

Another similar hadith

> Abu Qatadah narrated: "They asked the Prophet about when they sIept
> past the Salat. He said: 'There is no negligence in sleep, negligence
> is only while one is awake. So when one of you forgets a Salat, or
> sleeps through it, then let him pray it when he remembers it.'"
> https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:177

Comment: No what if sunrise is occuring? Then the qadhah salah wont even be counted